# How do I output a 2D char array using nested for loops?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am trying to output a simple 2D char array using nested for loops

It does not output in a "Square form", and also it is crashing.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char array[x][y] = {
        "000000",
        "0    0",
        "0    0",
        "000000",
    };

    for (int i = 1; i <=x; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <=y; j++)
               cout << array[i][j];
        }
}
```

Comment: for starters arrays are 0 based. you are accessing array[1][1], instead of starting at array[0][0]

Comment: What are `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 2):

C++ uses Zero-based indexing

your loops should be like

```
for (int i = 0; i <x; i++)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

That's why it's crashing

Also you don't print line breaks. Insert `cout << std::endl` in the outer loop

Comment: This wouldn't cause a crash. It's crashing because x and y are never declared or initialized.

Comment: Well that shouldn't even compile - but an off size index will likely cause an segmentation fault and subsequent crash

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize OP had <=, so I was thinking the index would still never go out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays are zero based, so you should loop from `0` to `x-1` rather than from `1` to `x`.

You also need a line break, otherwise it will all be written on the same line.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < y; i++) {
    cout << array[i][j];
  }
  cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that x and y are constants defined like

```
const size_t x = 4;
const size_t y = 7;
```

C++ does not allow to use non-constant expressions as array sizes though some compilers have their own language extensions that allow to use variable length arrays.

In this case this array

```
char array[x][y] = {
    "000000",
    "0    0",
    "0    0",
    "000000",
};
```

can be outputed the following way

```
for ( auto &s : array ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Take into account that indices of arrays in C++ start from 0. So if to use indices then the loop can look like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < x; i++ ) std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
```

Take into account that to output this shape there is no need to declare a 2D array.:)

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    size_t n = 4;
    size_t m = 6;
    char c = '*';

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << c 
                  << std::setfill( i % ( n - 1 ) == 0 ? c : ' ' ) 
                  << std::setw( m - 1 ) 
                  << c << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Its output is what you expect:)

```
******
*    *
*    *
******
```

Answer (score -1):

and can someone explain me why the second method outputs the array on other location ? i mean it starts to output on 2nd line while 1st method outputs from 00coord (by coord its mean location in console ,, not array position)

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    cout << array[i] << endl;




for (int i = 0; i <x; i++) {
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j <y; j++)
        cout << map[i][j];

}
```

Comment: Before outputing a row you inserted cout << endl; for (int i = 0; i <x; i++) {
    cout << endl; So you skipped the first line of the console.